# How to format help output for arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-s", "--scroll", type=int,help="Which direction to scroll",required=True)
```

Output will be like:

[image]

As you see it outputs (-s SCROLL, --scroll SCROLL)

How to simply change it to just (-s, --scroll) I need it to be on one line because now it kind of looks ugly and with more arguments even worse.

P.S. It works fine with one flag only but I need them both.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `argparse`?

Comment: Play with the `metavar` parameter.

Comment: @hpaulj Thaaaankss that's all I needed